# Modify WSDL Output Schema on ASMX .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wsdl, asmx

Im having an issue with asp.net asmx output schemas, I also tried WCF method. But still failed

I create a WSDL with .net ASMX and wanted to have an output like this

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieyYr.png)

But my code generated another output format like this one

[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taH2e.png)

I expected
SOAP-ENV:Body

- InquiryResponse

  - (Child Element)

Current format
soap:Body

- GetinquiryResponse

  - GetinquiryResult

    - (Child Element)

Here's my code on .asmx file
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQsfY.png)

Here's my model
[my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N64L3.png)

I also tried WCF and still getting same format. Thanks

Comment: Don't post code as images. SO has rich formatting for code, which can be copied or searched.